# How to copy latest file from sftp to local directory using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have multiple file in SFTP server from which I need to copy only latest file. I have written sample code but in that I am passing filename. What logic I need to add that it identify the latest file from sftp and copy it into my local?

In SFTP server -

```
my_data_20220428.csv
my_data_20220504.csv
my_data_20220501.csv
my_data_20220429.csv
```

The code which I am running-

```
datadir="/script/data"
cd ${datadir}
rm -f ${datadir}/my_data*.csv
rm -f ${logfile}
lftp<<END_SCRIPT
open sftp://${sftphost}
user ${sftpuser} ${sftppassword}
cd ${sftpfolder}
lcd $datadir
mget my_data_20220504.csv
bye
END_SCRIPT
```

what changes I need to do it automatically pick the latest file from server without hardcoding the filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this script mainly copied from your sample, so it is expected that the variables have already been created.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

datadir="/script/data"
rm -f "$datadir"/my_data*.csv
rm -f "$logfile"
new=$(echo "ls -halt $sftpfolder" | lftp -u "${sftpuser}","${sftppassword}" sftp://"${sftphost}" | sed -n '/my_data/s/.* \(.*\)/\1/p' | head -1)
lftp -u "${sftpuser}","${sftppassword}" sftp://"${sftphost}" << --EOF--
cd "$sftpfolder"
lcd "$datadir"
get "$new"
bye
--EOF--
```

Comment: ls: invalid option -- 'h'
ls: invalid option -- 'a'
ls: invalid option -- 't'
cd: Access failed: No such file (/imrmnt/vvtransform/script/data)
get: Access failed: No such file

Comment: getting access denied

Comment: sir where r u using ${sftpfolder}?

Comment: echo $new is giving empty result

Comment: the name of file is - ey_imr_ai_data_20220504.csv

Comment: still giving the empty in new

Comment: Sir can u pls help me?

Comment: sir not giving result.

Comment: using this ---- new=$(echo ls -l | lftp -u "${sftpuser}","${sftppassword}" sftp://"${sftphost}" | sed -n '/ey_imr_ai_data/s/.* \(.*\)/\1/p' | head -1)

Comment: sir without using $sftpfolder how will get the files?

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx   0 0        0             387 Apr 25 09:01 ey_imr_ai_data_20220425.csv
-rwxrwxrwx   0 0        0          376837 Apr 29 13:24 ey_imr_ai_data_20220429.csv
-rwxrwxrwx   0 0        0             231 Apr 30 09:01 ey_imr_ai_data_20220430.csv
-rwxrwxrwx   0 0        0             231 May  1 09:01 ey_imr_ai_data_20220501.csv
-rwxrwxrwx   0 0        0          375451 May  3 13:01 ey_imr_ai_data_20220503.csv
-rwxrwxrwx   0 0        0          376961 May  4 13:01 ey_imr_ai_data_20220504.csv
-rwxrwxrwx   0 0        0          382612 May  5 13:01 ey_imr_ai_data_20220505.csv

Comment: head -1 is giving oldest file but when I am using tail -1 then it is giving latest file

Comment: @Shivika Okay, change to tail and run script. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
latest=$(lftp "sftp://$sftpuser:$sftppassword@$sftphost" \
         -e "cd $sftpfolder; glob rels -1t *.csv; bye" |
         head -1)
lftp "sftp://$sftpuser:$sftppassword@myhost" \
-e "cd $sftpfolder; mget $latest; bye"
```

Comment: I am not getting where I need to add your logic in my script?

Comment: I mean if possible can u pls edit my script and your part.

Comment: Remove everything from `lftp<<END_SCRIPT` onward and replace with my answer.

Comment: rels: invalid option -- '1'
rels: invalid option -- 't'
rels: Access failed: No such file (*.csv)

Comment: getting this sir

Comment: process stuck in this line - cd `/Engagements/CTP-Offering/PromomatMLR/USEDPRMDEVRSG01/PromomatDev-MVP00O/JNJ/OUT/Reports' [Connecting...]

Comment: maybe try `glob rels *.csv`. I edited the answer. Sorry I haven't used `lftp` much.

Comment: Getting access failed- no such file

Comment: can you add `echo "$latest"` in between the two commands to see if its finding a file? The idea here is to use `lftp` to list files arranged by date, grab the newest file by piping to `head -n 1` in the shell, and pass that back to `mget`. Maybe add `-q` to the first lftp: `lftp -q`.

Comment: okay sir let me check

Comment: It is picking most older file not latest one..my_data_20220428.csv

Comment: Make sure it is actually the oldest by running `ls -l` on the server to see that actual modified date. Remember we are looking at date last modified, not the name. If it is really oldest, you can you switch to the opposite file by switching `head -n 1` to `tail -n 1`.

Comment: Sir where are you using $datadir?

Comment: sir 1 doubt, without using $datadir, how it can be copy file into local dir

Comment: Yes I added `lcd "$datadir"`, it will probably work now. But looks like you worked it out.